# build failed if I set the disable to easy-todo options

Tags: easy-todo

I just found that passing a `disable` option cause build failure, I create a simple code to reproduce the same error:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[disable]{easy-todo} %this failed
%\usepackage[enable]{easy-todo} %this works OK

\begin{document}

\section{good}

\todo{hi}

\end{document}
```

The error log message are:

```
! You can't use `\unskip' in vertical mode.
\todo #1->\todoii {#1}{#1}\unskip 

l.9 \todo{hi}

Sorry...I usually can't take things from the current page.
Try `I\vskip-\lastskip' instead.
```

But if I use the `enable` option, it works OK.
Any idea to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error is inability to implement a command in vertical mode, you can skip it with `\leavevmode` and enter in horizontal mode.

**Code**

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[disable]{easy-todo} 

\begin{document}

\section{good}

\leavevmode\todo{hi}

\end{document}
```

**Update**

Or an equivalent

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[disable]{easy-todo} 
\let\oldtodo\todo
\renewcommand{\todo}{\leavevmode\oldtodo}
\begin{document}

\section{good}

\todo{hi}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. You mean, to fix this issue, I need to replace all the `\todo{...}` in my tex file to `\leavevmode\todo{...}`?

Comment: Or simply in the preamble you can add  `\let\oldtodo\todo`
`\renewcommand{\todo}{\leavevmode\oldtodo}` without changing anything in your document.

Comment: Oh, thanks, this works like a charm. I think this can also be a good add in to the answer.